# What is the file size limit for a video using the media webpart in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, web-part, file-upload, video

I want to upload a video to my publishing page in SharePoint 2010 using the media webpart. Are there any limitations to file size that I should be aware of that would cause issues with the webpart.

I also am planning to upload several videos to be displayed across multiple pages this way, and want to make sure that site performance isn't affected too heavily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what ever your file upload size limit, will apply to video files as well. Lets say, if you set file upload size limit to 100 MB (Default 50MB for 2010) then you can upload 100MB file size including video files.

You have to careful about uploading the large video files, as these will hurt your SharePoint performance.

Read this more information: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sanjaynarang/2010/05/26/media-web-part-in-sharepoint-2010-faq/

[Plan for caching and performance (SharePoint Server 2010)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee424404(v=office.14).aspx)